# Generate random coordinates for clustered items

Tags: java, kotlin

I'm trying to generate a deterministic 2D visual map of a clustered set of points.

For example, for these following clusters:

```
[
  [ 1, 2, 3 ],
  [ 4 ],
  [ 5, 6 ]
]
```

A visualisation for a possible output (out of infinite possibilities) would be:

[image: Possible visualisation of clusters]

I thought of generating equally distributed random points with the same amount of clusters, so that these would be the "roots" of each visual cluster. Then I'd be able to randomise other points around them.

However, I need the output to be deterministic. Is there any way to make sure I get the same results on every run?

I'm can use either Java or Kotlin - in case there's a library for this purpose - but verbal suggestions are equally helpful.

Comment: You can set the random seed to a known value at the start to get determinism.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really follow the big picture here.  But the specific issue of repeatable randomness is easy to solve.  Simply create a [Random](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.random/-random/) object with a fixed seed, e.g.:

```
val myRandom = kotlin.random.Random(1)
```

Then it will give the same pseudo-random sequence each time.

(You'll need to create a new instance like this every time you want to perform a repeatable action, so it might not be terribly efficient.)